# PHP&MySQL insert data error

Tags: php, mysql, insert

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $sql_insert_data = "INSERT INTO games (title, my_platform, genre, type, release_date, publisher, developer, metacritic, "
            . "completed, dlc_extensions, achievements_support, 100_achievements) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    $result_insert_data = $connect->query($sql_insert_data);
    $secure_insert = mysqli($sql_insert_data);

    $secure_insert->bind_param(
        'xyz', 
        $_POST['title'], 
        $_POST['my_platform'], 
        $_POST['genre'], 
        $_POST['type'], 
        $_POST['release_date'],
        $_POST['publisher'],
        $_POST['developer'],
        $_POST['metacritic'],
        $_POST['completed'],
        $_POST['dlc_extensions'],
        $_POST['achievements_support'],
        $_POST['100_achievements']
    );   

    $secure_insert->execute();
    echo "Inserted"

} else {
    echo "Something is wrong";
}
```

Hello guys Im new here so please about patience. I have no idea how to fix this problem. The eror is following:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Games_Project_List\index.php:91 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Games_Project_List\index.php on line 91

Thank you for help in advance.

Comment: `bind_param('xyz' ... keep going` and what on earth does `xyz` represent?

Comment: your `echo "Something is wrong";` didn't help you here.

Comment: `$secure_insert = mysqli` is invalid. That isn't the right method.

Comment: A: Read the manual please http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and use the right syntax. Your question contains too many errors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it contains too many errors and reading the manual on using a prepared statement properly obviously was not followed to the letter.

Comment: At least he is trying to use `mysqli`...we are not here just to answer expert on the field, questions...also a good way to start should be, like, give you one day and read all the content on http://www.phptherightway.com/

Answer (score -1):

Let's take a look about **bind_param**:

```
bool mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

As you can see, you have to set the types of the variables, you can use the following types:

- i -  corresponding variable has type integer
- d -  corresponding variable has type double
- s -  corresponding variable has type string
- b -  corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

```
$result_insert_data = $connect->query($sql_insert_data);

$secure_insert = mysqli($sql_insert_data);
```

You never reuse `$result_insert_data` for as far as I know, which makes me wonder if you didn't mixed up two versions of your code after a merge.

Also, I may be wrong, but I don't recall a function called mysqli, which is what your server is also thinking.